# Over lapping shadows on collection view cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, shadow, iglistkit

I'm trying to add a shadow to each collection view cell within a section controller with IGListKit, but the shadows overlap on to other cells causing a line to appear at the top/bottom.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting `minimumLineSpacing` or `minimumInteritemSpacing` (depending on how your collection view is set up)?

Comment: I hadn't but doesn't seem to be making much of a difference. I'm using IGListKit for my collection view. Should of probably added that.

Answer (score 0):

For your case: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/issues/335

Have you tried it?

Try this solution: set Inset, not LineSpacing

[image: Settings]

Comment: I am using IGListKit

Comment: I have updated an anser. I found solution in IGListKit github page

Comment: Inset is for the sections not the cells within the sections. I believe the issue is that the shadow I'm setting on the cell is going over the cell on top of below it.

Comment: Did you try to set `self.minimumInteritemspacing = 10` like on the image inside section controller?

Comment: Try set more than 0.

Comment: Makes no difference. Looks like when you scroll a collection view the z index changes so when you scroll back up the show is now appearing again.